# SqlGrammerException in Hibernate program

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

When I insert or save only one record to MySQL, it works fine. But when I insert more than two records using `create` property (not`update`), it throws an `SqlGrammerException` exception.

The following is the code:

```
package com.aartek.DTO;

public class UserDTO 
{
    private int id;  
    private String firstName,aka,houseName;  

    public int getId() 
    {  
        return id;  
    }  

    public void setId(int id) 
    {  
        this.id = id;  
    }  

    public String getFirstName() 
    {  
        return firstName;  
    }  

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {  
        this.firstName = firstName;  
    }  

    public String getAka() {
        return aka;
    }

    public void setAka(String aka) {
        this.aka = aka;
    }

    public String getHouseName() {
        return houseName;
    }

    public void setHouseName(String houseName) {
        this.houseName = houseName;
    }  
}
```

testAdd class:

```
package com.aartek.DTO;
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class TestAdd 
{
    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception
    {
        UserDTO dto=new UserDTO();
        UserDTO dto2=new UserDTO();
        UserDTO dto3=new UserDTO();

        dto.setFirstName("Eddard_Stark");
        dto.setAka("NED/Lord_of_winterfall");
        dto.setHouseName("Stark");

        dto2.setFirstName("Tyrion_lannister");
        dto2.setAka("Imp/Hand_of_the_queen");
        dto2.setHouseName("Lannister");

        dto3.setFirstName("Dannereous_Targareyen");
        dto3.setAka("Mother_of_Dragons");
        dto3.setHouseName("Targareyen");

        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernet.cfg.xml");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();

        Session s=sessionFactory.openSession();

        Transaction t=s.beginTransaction();

        s.save(dto);
        s.save(dto2);
        s.save(dto3);
        t.commit();
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
          "C:\Users\s\.tooling\Desktop\hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>  

 <session-factory>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/suyash</property>
  <property name="connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="connection.password">root</property>

  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
 <mapping resource="userDTO.hbm.xml" />    
 </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Hibernate-mapping file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
 "C:\Users\s\.tooling\Desktop\hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  

 <hibernate-mapping package = "com.aartek.DTO">  
  <class name="UserDTO" table="WESTEROUS_ISLE">  
    <id name="id" column="CHARACTER">  
     <generator class="increment"></generator>  
    </id>  

    <property name="firstName" column="FIRST_of_his_NAME"></property>  
    <property name="aka" column="A.K.A"></property>  
    <property name="houseName" column="HOUSE_NAME"></property>

  </class>  

 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: display more about `SqlGrammerException`

Comment: full stack trace would be ideal